# If $(1-i)^n = 2^n$ , then find $n$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> If $$(1-i)^n = 2^n$$ then find $n$.

If anything raised to $0$ is $1$, but according to my book $ n \ne 0$. Is the print wrong?

Comment: If raising things to the power of $0$ results in $1$, why do you think that $n=1$?

Comment: Sorry, I typed it wrong.

Comment: Factorize by two, you get : $e^{\frac{ni\pi}{4}} = 1$ when simplifying the $2^n$

Comment: @mvggz The absolute values don't cancel out.

Comment: Maybe, that was not my point, merely factorizing to get something interesting. There is a "-" in the exponant. But you're right that's $\sqrt{2}$ that should have been factorized

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is true only for $n=0$, since
$$
\left| (1-i)^n\right|=\big(\sqrt{2}\big)^n=2^{n/2}.
$$
Thus, if $(1-i)^n=2^n$, then $2^{n/2}=\left| (1-i)^n\right|=2^n$, and hence $n=0$.

**Note.** However, what happens more often is
$$
 (1-i)^{2n}=2^n.
$$
Indeed, $(1-i)^{2}=-2i$, and $(1-i)^{4}=-4$, and $(1-i)^8=16$.

In fact
$$
 (1-i)^{2n}=2^n\quad\text{if and only if}\quad n=4k.
$$

Answer (score 3):

$(1-i)^n=2^n$

$(1-i)^n/(1+i)^n\times (1+i)^n =2^n$

$2^n/(1+i)^n=2^n$

$(1+i)^n=1$

$n=0$